# Is it sufficient to have only English for Terms and Conditions?

Tags: multilingual, terms-of-use

I'm developing a multi tenancy site which will have more than 1000 active users every day. I'm not sure about the legal perspective for my Terms and Conditions.

If I have 80% of the users in lets say, Sweden. Can I offer only T&C in English? Probably a specific question to the country itself though.

Comment: Is the site itself in multiple languages?

Comment: @w3dk: Yes, it's 3 different languages.

Comment: Well, I would think you would need (at least for usability) the T&Cs in each language you serve your content in (the languages you "support") - regardless of location. From a "legal" perspective I can't really say.

Comment: Sufficient for what?   The answer will be different depending on whether you want to avoid being sued in your country, have users know what is going on, or satisfy terms of use requirements of third party partners such as advertisers.

Comment: I am with both w3dk and Stephen Ostermiller. If you want your terms and conditions to be followed, it makes sense to have it written in each language that makes sense. Chinese may not be one of them. ;-) However, for our intended audience, it makes sense to provide your terms and conditions to at least cover your bases and minimize any issues you are trying to avoid.

Comment: What is the point of having T&C if people cant read them?

Answer (score 1):

What is the official language of the jurisdiction that would settle any legal argument?

Many T&Cs will have a clause along the lines of "*Any dispute will be settled in the courts of...*"
In many jurisdictions, the courts won't rule upon documents that are not written in an official language of the country.

This means that you provide your "Master" T&Cs in your home language - let's say English.  You can then provide translations into other languages, like Swedish, but they will carry the same clause about the *courts of England & Wales*.

But remember, if you are getting into the realms of protecting against legal challenges, you will be better served by asking this question of a lawyer.

Answer (score -2):

If there are 1000 active user then probably you have to use each language in T&C. Depends on which country user are going to read T&C accordingly.